# Arduino 1.0.2: no matching function for call to 'Serial_::write(byte [2],int)'

Tags: arduino, serial, imu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arduino Razor IMU with Serial.write(id, 2): Can’t have 2 parameters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49854/arduino-razor-imu-with-serial-writeid-2-cant-have-2-parameters)

I've posted this item [before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49854/arduino-razor-imu-with-serial-writeid-2-cant-have-2-parameters).

I downloaded the [Razor IMU source code](https://dev.qu.tu-berlin.de/attachments/download/1226/Razor%20AHRS%20Firmware%20and%20Test%20Sketch%20v1.4.1.zip) last night from [Razor AHRS](https://dev.qu.tu-berlin.de/projects/sf-razor-9dof-ahrs/files). This code uses exactly the sensors I need and would solve the problem I have currently (I hope). The only problem is that on line 535 in "Razor AHRS v1.4.1\Arduino\Razor_AHRS\Razor_AHRS.pde" in the above linked zip file they have:

```
Serial.write(id, 2);
```

When I Verify, compilation fails at this line with the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'Serial_::write(byte [2],int)'
```

I downloaded and installed Arduino 1.0.2 on a new pc and installed the drivers to Arduino Pro Micro 16MHz/5V.

I checked the [arduino](http://arduino.cc/) documentation on [Serial.write](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) and it seems to be a valid command.

What am I doing wrong?